# Hyperref doesn't highlight cites

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, documentclass-writing

When I load `hyperref` inside my own class definition wrapped in `AtEndDocument` from the `etoolbox` package, my cites aren't colored. But all used section references get colored.

I could figure out that all cite will be colored when hyperref is loaded directly.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testclass.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{testclass}[2018-02-27 v0.1 Test class]
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \LoadClass{scrartcl}

    \RequirePackage[%
     backend = biber
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

    % Working for ref
    % But not for cite
    \AtEndPreamble{%
        \RequirePackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{colorlinks}
    }

    \AtEndDocument{%
        \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    }%

    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{testclass}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Working both for ref and cite
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello world}\label{sec:hello}
        Hello world \cite{doody}
    \section{What ever}
        If've no idea~\ref{sec:hello}
\end{document}
```

My question is now how can I color cite when `hyperref` is loaded inside my custom class? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a 'race condition' in `\AtEndPreamble`. `biblatex` does its `hyperref` set-up in `\AtEndPreamble`, and you load `hyperref` only in `\AtEndPreamble`. Since your `\AtEndPreamble` comes in later than `biblatex`'s `\AtEndPreamble` code, `hyperref` is not loaded when `biblatex` does its setup.

One solution is to move your `\AtEndPreamble` to before you load `biblatex`

```
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2018-02-27 v0.1 Test class]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\LoadClass{scrartcl}

% Working for ref
% But not for cite
\AtEndPreamble{%
    \RequirePackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks}
}

\RequirePackage[%
 backend = biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
}%

\endinput
```

This is similar to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/585. If you must have the `\AtEndPreamble` loading `hyperref` *after* loading `biblatex`, you can use `hyperref=manual`, but you will have to issue `\BiblatexManualHyperrefOn` after you've loaded `hyperref` manually yourself.

Comment: I've marked this answer as solution because it describes the problem and it is simplier. @UlrikeFischer Your solution is working also fine :)

Answer (score 6):

Well at least I'm not alone. See this discussion here https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/585.

You can use the commands mentioned in the discussion:

```
\begin{filecontents}{testclass.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{testclass}[2018-02-27 v0.1 Test class]
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \LoadClass{scrartcl}

    \RequirePackage[%
     backend = biber,
     hyperref=manual
    ]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

    % Working for ref
    % But not for cite
    \AtEndPreamble{%
        \RequirePackage{hyperref}
        \BiblatexManualHyperrefOn
        \hypersetup{colorlinks}
    }

    \AtEndDocument{%
        \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    }%

    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{testclass}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Working both for ref and cite
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello world}\label{sec:hello}
        Hello world \cite{doody}
    \section{What ever}
        If've no idea~\ref{sec:hello}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although in this case one could also move `\AtEndPreamble` before `\RequirePackage{biblatex}`

Comment: @moewe This is a minimal document. One can't know the reason why hyperref is placed there -- there can be easily other packages involved in the real class.

Comment: That's true. I just want to keep people away from `hyperref=manual` for as long as possible. It should really only be used if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions @moewe and @UlrikeFischer. The real class is indeed more complexe but it should be possible to just move the `\AtEndPreamble`. I'll mark one solution after I've successfully tested it with the real class.